# How do I get the program to check if the key is "equal" to the value?

Tags: ruby, key-value

I was trying to write a simple username/password prompt. I'm still a beginner with Ruby.

```
    combo = Hash.new
combo["placidlake234"] = "tastychicken"
combo["xxxdarkmasterxxx"] = "pieisgood"
combo["dvpshared"] = "ilikepie"

puts "Enter your username."
username = gets.chomp

def user_check
  if username = ["placidlake234"||"xxxdarkmasterxxx"||"dvpshared"]
    puts "What is your password?"
    password = gets.chomp
    pass_check
  else
    puts "Your username is incorrect."
  end
end

def pass_check
  if password => username
    puts "You have signed into #{username}'s account."
  end
end

user_check()
```

When I try running it, I get a strange error right before username in `=> username`.

Comment: If you're working in Ruby on Rails, the Devise module automates username/password check.

Comment: A few problems: 1. combo is not used; 2. ["placidlake234" || "xxxdarkmasterxxx" || "dvpshared"]=> ["placidlake234"], so you have if username = ["placidlake234"], which is if ["placidlake234"], which is always true, since you mistakenly used = rather than ==; 3. you need def passcheck(password, username), to give passcheck() access to those variables; 4. you want if password == username (not =>); 5. it is not common practice to insist that a password is the same as a username; 6. you need user_check(username) for user_check to have access to username. You got StrangeRuntimeError?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which should be corrected:
I have commented out below

```
combo = Hash.new
combo["placidlake234"] = "tastychicken"
combo["xxxdarkmasterxxx"] = "pieisgood"
combo["dvpshared"] = "ilikepie"

puts "Enter your username."
username = gets.chomp

def user_check(username, combo)
  #HERE combo.keys gives keys. 
  if combo.keys.include? username
    puts "What is your password?"
    password = gets.chomp
    if pass_check(username, password, combo)
      puts "You have signed into #{username}'s account." 
    else
      puts "Wrong password, sorrie"
    end
  else
    puts "Your username is incorrect."
  end
end

def pass_check(username, password, combo)
  #Here, access by combo[username]
  return true if password == combo[username]
  false
end

#HERE, pass the arguments, so that it is available in function scope
user_check(username, combo)
```